# Select average based on length batch from Table object in Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I've created a `BatchTableEnvironment` in `Apache Flink` and loaded some data into a `Table` object named `HTable`. In this data there are a `ID, DateTime, Result, UnixDateTime` columns. These are of `INT, Timestamp, Double, Long` datatype. Now I want create another table that filters the `HTable` in a way that it creates a tumble average based on the `Result` column of the last 100 rows. So a average result for row 1-100, 101-200 etc. So the average should be based on rownumbers or by ID, and not by time. The problem is that I dont know the exact syntax for this. See my code below.

```
        Table AverageTable = HTable
           .filter("ID.isNotNull && dateTime.isNotNull && result.isNotNull && unixDateTime.isNotNull")
           .select("ID, dateTime, result, unixDateTime")
           .window(Tumble.over("100.rows").on("dateTime").as("movingAverage100"))
            .groupBy("movingAverage100")
           .select("avg(result) as avgResult");
```

Comment: HTable , is it Hbase source ?

Comment: No, the source is a CSV file.

Comment: can you try .window(Tumble over 10.rows)
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-11%3A+Table+API+Stream+Aggregations

Comment: When I try this: ``Table table = HTable.window(Tumble.over("2.rows").on("dateTime").as("a")).groupBy("mType");`` I get the following error: ``org.apache.flink.table.api.WindowGroupedTable cannot be converted to org.apache.flink.table.api.Table``. And when I remove the group by clause I get the same error.